# Cisco catalyst and Juniper SRX240 vlan routing

Tags: cisco-catalyst, juniper-srx

I think my understanding of Trunking is off. I have two cisco switches under two vlans, connected to a single SRX240. I have connectivity to the SRX from the switch but not anywhere past it. The switch can ping 192.168.8.4 under vlan 89 but cannot ping 192.168.16.2 under vlan 16.

THE SRX CONFIGS

```
interfaces {
ge-0/0/0 {
    unit 0 {
        description "Eric's Connection";
        family ethernet-switching {
            port-mode access;
            vlan {
                members Group-16;
            }
        }
    }
}
ge-0/0/1 {
    unit 0 {
        description "JSS's Connection";
        family ethernet-switching {
            port-mode access;
            vlan {
                members JSS-89;
            }
        }
    }
}
ge-0/0/2 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            vlan {
                members vlan-trust;
            }
        }
    }
}
ge-0/0/3 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            vlan {
                members vlan-trust;
            }
        }
    }
}
ge-0/0/4 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            vlan {
                members vlan-trust;
            }
        }
    }
}
vlan {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 192.168.1.1/24;
        }
    }
    unit 16 {
        family inet {
            address 192.168.16.2/24;
        }
    }
    unit 89 {
        family inet {
            address 192.168.8.4/24;
        }
    }
}
```

}

THE SWITCH CONFIGS

```
 interface FastEthernet1/0/1
 switchport access vlan 89
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/2
 switchport access vlan 89
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/3
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/4
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/5
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/6
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/7
 switchport access vlan 89
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/8
 switchport access vlan 89
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/9
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/10
 switchport access vlan 89
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/11
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/12
 switchport access vlan 89
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/13
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/14
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/15
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan89
 ip address 192.168.8.3 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
```

FE1/0/10 is the connection to the SRX.

Any guidance would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to explain this a little better. On the switch configuration, you only have one VLAN. Interface `FastEthernet1/0/1` is configured as a trunk, but you don't say to what is it connected. You are not trunking to the SRX. Since these are two separate VLANs, you need to use a router (or the layer-3 routing part of a layer-3 switch) to get traffic from one VLAN to another. That means the switch will need a default gateway in its VLAN globally defined in its configuration: `ip default-gateway <gateway address>`

Comment: F1/0/1 is connect to a WLC. Sorry, I actually messed with the configs just before posting this. This is what it looks like now.

interface FastEthernet1/0/10
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
end
 

But with this, I cannot reach 192.168.8.4 on the router. The VLAN 16 is on another cisco switch with the same sort of configurations set.

Thanks.

Comment: The switch has no idea how to reach a different network without a default gateway. Any traffic destined for another network needs to go through the default gateway, which you have not defined.

Comment: Makes sense. I've added a default route to 192.168.8.4. However with whats configured now, i still cant reach 192.168.8.4.

thanks again

Comment: Is the SRX configured for access interfaces and to allow ICMP? You cannot trunk on one side and access on the other side of a link.

Comment: I have a zone trust with 'host-inbound-traffic system services all' enabled. That is in a policy that configured for zone trust to zone trust.

Comment: I still don't see why you are configuring VLANs on the SRX interfaces if the switch is connected with an access interface. An access interface will not tag frames with VLAN tags, which are only used on trunks. Properly, an access interface should drop frames with VLAN tags as malformed. Doing otherwise can lead to security problems, e.g. VLAN hopping.

Comment: I see. Ill take those off and see where it takes me. Thanks again

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the switches will need a default gateway to reach IP addresses on other subnets.
Configure the 192.168.8.4 as the default gateway IP on 1 switch

```
ip default gateway 192.168.8.4
```

and 192.168.16.2 as the default gateway on the other.

Comment: You cannot put in a default route on a layer-2 switch. The `ip default-gateway <gateway address>` command is for layer-2 switches. The `ip route` command would only be used on layer-3 switches that have `ip routing` enabled.

Comment: Yes corrected now. Thanks for pointing it out, Ron.